# Microsoft Graph - How to get share point sites

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Is there anyway to get a list of Sharepoint Online sites equivalent to the Get-SPOsite cmdlet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use the [Search for Sites endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/site-search?view=graph-rest-1.0) and pass a wildcard as your query. See example below:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites?search=*
```

This will return all sites in the tenant.

Comment: This appears to lack group sites?